# React Native - TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined when focus on textinput

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

After updating the React Native version to 0.70.6, I get this error when I focus any textinput.

[image]

Comment: Are you doing something on focus? 
The question is too vague. Please edit the question and add some relevant code.

Comment: @AhmadNaeem It only happens when the input is focused. no other action.

Comment: Please add some code relevant to this question, it's hard to guess what's the problem from this alone.

Comment: @MustafaUysal did you figure this out? Facing the same issue on my ios builds